# AWK sub function syntax

Tags: regex, awk

I have a file with the contents:

```
aaa.bbb.ccc ddd.eee.fff.ggg h.i.j.k
```

If I use the code:

- `awk '{sub(/\.$/, ""); print $1}' test.txt`
  Returns: `aaa.bbb.ccc`
- `awk '{sub(/\.$/, ""); print $3}' test.txt`
  Returns: `h.i.j.k`

I understand the sub function is used as `sub(regexp, replacement, target)`. I don't understand `\.$/` from the sub function. What is the `.$`?

If I apply this to a real example,

/usr/bin/host 172.0.0.10

01.0.0.172.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer hostname.domain.com.

1. `/usr/bin/host 172.0.0.10 | /bin/awk '{sub(/\.$/, ""); print $5}'`
   gives: `hostname.domain.com`
2. `/usr/bin/host 172.0.0.10| /bin/awk '{sub(/\.$/, ""); print $1}'`
   gives: `10.0.0.172.in-addr.arpa`

- The sub function will match to the end of the line as there is a `.`
- What is the `""` doing?
- How is awk splitting things into columns?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
sub(/regexp/, replacement, target)
sub(/\.$/, replacement, target)
```

Your regexp is `\.$`, not `.$/`

`\` is the escape character. It escapes the character that follows it, thus stripping it from the `regex` meaning and processing it literally.

`.` in `regex` matches any single character. Unless it's escaped by `\` like in your example, thus it just matches the dot character `.`

`$` simply means the end of the line.

Putting this together, `\.$` is an escaped dot at the end of the line. This would match for example any end of paragraph that ends in a period.

In your example, the `sub` doesn't substitute anything because there is no `.` at the end of the line (your input ends with `.k`. So your first `awk` just prints the 1st column, and the other one prints the 3rd column.

**Update**

For your updated question.

Awk splits a string in columns by whitespace by default. Thus in your input, columns are like this:

```
 01.0.0.172.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer hostname.domain.com.
|----------$1-----------|--$2--|-$3-|--$4---|----------$5--------|
```

in your `sub` command, awk finds the dot at the end of the line and replaces with `""` which is the empty string (i.e. it just deletes it)

So your 1st command - `{sub(/.$/, ""); print $5}`, it prints the 5th column which is `hostname.domain.com.` after it replaces the `.` at the end with nothing (deletes it). It's worth noting that in this regex you don't escape the `.` anymore, so the pattern just matches *any* character at the end and deletes it (it happens to be a `.` in your input)

Your other command - `{sub(/.$/, ""); print $1}` deletes the character at the very end of the line and then just prints the first column `10.0.0.172.in-addr.arpa`

You can also set custom column separators in awk, I recommend you read some introduction and tutorials on awk to have a better understanding of how it works. E.g. [simple awk tutorial](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~dholland/computers/awk.html)

Comment: thanks, you are good at explaining things.  I have expanded. see update

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to step me through this, i understand now!  I did not know about the split by white space by default and thought it was doing something clever with the "."  A very constructive answer and i will read awk and regex further.  cheers for your time, kudos!

Answer (score 5):

`sub(regexp, replacement, target)`

So here we used the regex as `\.$`, which matches the dot at the end. Here `sub(/\.$/, "")` we didn't mention the target so it takes `$0` ie the whole line. If you specify any target , it would remove the last dot only on that particular column.

```
awk '{sub(/\.$/, ""); print $1}' test.txt
```

Removes a dot which was present only at the end of the line and prints only the column 1. If there is no dot at the last, then replacement won't occur.

```
awk '{sub(/\.$/, ""); print $3}' test.txt
```

Removes the dot at the end of the line and prints only the column 3. Because of there is no dot at the end, it returns the third column aka last column as it is.

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
aaa.bbb.ccc. ddd.eee.fff.ggg h.i.j.k.
$ awk '{sub(/\.$/, ""); print $1}' file
aaa.bbb.ccc.
$ awk '{sub(/\.$/, ""); print $3}' file
h.i.j.k
```

Answer (score -1):

I had one table with this format

```
<table width="700" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="ffcc00" bgcolor="ffcc00">
<tbody>
        <th colspan="7" bordercolor="ffcc00" bgcolor="000000" scope="col">
            <div align="center" class="style2">
                Exciter Power Supply</div>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="175" bordercolor="ffcc00" bgcolor="000000" scope="col">
            <div align="center" class="style1">+ 3 V </div>
        </th>
        <th width="175" bordercolor="ffcc00" bgcolor="000000" scope="col">
            <div align="center" class="style1">
                OK</div>
        </th>
        <th width="175" bordercolor="ffcc00" bgcolor="000000" scope="col">
            <div align="center" class="style1">&nbsp;+ 5 V</div>
        </th>
        <th width="175" bordercolor="ffcc00" bgcolor="000000" scope="col">
            <div align="center" class="style1">
                OK</div>
        </th>
    </tr>
    
</tbody>
```

When i get the value of **+3 V**

```
curl -s http://my-site/index.htm | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' | awk '/+ 3 V/{getline;  print}'
```

I had the output OK'&nbsp'; + 5 V

For remove blank space and text of another field i use sub() for change caracters plus tr to remove the caracters

```
curl -s http://my-site/index.htm | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' | awk '/+ 3 V/{getline; sub(/+ 5 V/, ""); print}' | tr "&nbsp;" " "
```

My output is only **OK**